# heroku don't run migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed an app to heroku, and after I ran:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

heroku ran some migrations but not all of them

I checked the db versions with

```
heroku run rake db:version
Running `rake db:version` attached to terminal... up, run.9949
Current version: 20131206153652
```

and

```
rake db:version
Current version: 20140102125131
```

both are in diferent versions of the DB, but how can I said to heroku that I need to run ALL the migrations.

Comment: Have you pushed all of your migrations to Heroku? Does Heroku *know* that there are other migrations to run?

Comment: Try running `git status` and check wheteher there are any migration files in 'untracked files' section. On a seperate question: you didn't alter any existing migration, right?

Comment: yeah, I didn't modified any migration, thanks Gareth after read your post I checked the migrations, I was working In a diferent branch named "development", I solved it doing.

`git push heroku development:master`, and after that, running the migrations in the same way. thanks :)

Comment: @BroiSatse you should post that as an answer and it should be marked as Accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by doing: 

`git push heroku development:master`

I was working in a different branch, thanks @gareth